# Indexing of tuples in a large PSQL JSONB array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB column `"deps"` like this

```json
[
  [
    {
      "name": "A"
    },
    "823"
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "B"
    },
    "332"
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "B"
    },
    "311"
  ]
]
```

The dictionary `{"name": "B"}` always comes first in the tuple. The number of tuples (items in the array) varies between zero and 15K

Is it possible to create an index of the items by `"name"` field of the dictionary?

Will such index improve performance of search for all rows containing

`"name" = "B"` or `"name" = "C"` ?

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM the_table
 WHERE deps @> ANY (
                    ARRAY [
                           '[[{"name": "B"}]]',
                           '[[{"name": "C"}]]'
                          ]::jsonb[]
                   );
```

I have discovered that the time of query above does not depend much on the size of the array in the ANY argument. It seems that PSQL creates a temporary (?) index when looking for B, consequent lookup for "C" runs fast.
The table is quite large ~300GB, 25M rows

Comment: The index you want to create depends on the query (and operator) you are using. So you will need to show us your query in order to be able to sugges a suitable index definition

Comment: I think you know the query UPDATE the_table
   SET stats = null
WHERE deps @> '[[{"name": "B"}]]'

Comment: It seems like you could simply model that data in a table. No need to (a)buse JSON when relational means are available. Then you could use simple indexes.

Comment: @stickybit The model is a set of ~2M  graphs between 50 to 15K nodes

Comment: @Larytet: Well, what you showed is a list of a string and a number. I don't know this encodes a graph but that doesn't matter, the thing is, that it could easily translate to a table with a string and a number column where the string column is indexed. And even if the actual thing was of variable structure (so that relational means aren't really possible), it seems there is always a name. So it could be a table with a string column `name`, indexed and a JSON with the part of the data that has a variable structure.

Comment: @stickybit in my case a table where rows contain data from the deps column would have  a few billions (10^12) of rows. My application is Ok with getting a flat list, a JSON array.  But occasionally I need to update a few rows matching some condition

Comment: @Larytet: OK? So some number of rows, that's what a relational DBMS is built for. And that doesn't change the structure of the data, which is the point. It may be even worse for performance when the JSONs per row are large.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241100/discussion-between-larytet-and-sticky-bit).

Comment: 'It seems that PSQL creates a temporary (?) index when looking for B, consequent lookup for "C" runs fast.'  Seems like an unsound discovery. I wouldn't trust that without seeing the evidence for it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not relevant anymore. The question is niche